# Do I need Kalman Filter after I read DMP data on MPU6050?

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

In my project I need to use as noiseless as possible data from a MPU6050, I do have some nice DMP data, what will happen if I apply Kalman filter above it? Will I get more noiseless data? Or will it become unreliable anymore? Are there any benefits to do that ?

Comment: That would entirely depend on your filter - do a good job and you can remove noise and trivialities from the signal, but do a bad job and you can remove any meaning.   Keep in mind that micrco-machined accelerometers have limitations - integrating to a position is a loosing proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DMP data from the MPU6050 is already filtered, and while I have not expirimented with the DMP data much myself I believe it is pretty clean. If there is a calibration process you can do to improve it, that is probably worth expirimenting with, but you should not filter the values a second time.

You should figure out what your application's noise tolerance actually is before worrying about different filters. There are potential benefits to your own filter, I think knowing exactly how it performs in edge cases and being able to calibrating it to your specific problem could be beneficial; However, it could also end up being worse than the DMP. Don't forget that filter calculations can generally take a few milliseconds for an arduino to run that you don't have to worry about with the DMP.

If you do work on your own filter, you will need to turn off the DMP and filter the raw values. Look into complementary, mahoney, and madgwick filters as well as kalman, which is quite computationally expensive. Using an existing library or an implementation from an open source quadcopter project is probably most efficient. The math associated with kalman filters and 3d rotations gets very complicated very quickly.